# How to add item to listbox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I am creating a simple GUI program to manage priorities. I am having troubles with adding items to the listbox. I tried to create an instance of Priority class by passing two attributes to the constructor and then use **g.listBox.insert(END, item)**, but it seems it doesn't work like that. I am getting an error:

> /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/cali/PycharmProjects/priorities/priorities.py
>   Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1553, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/priorities/priorities.py", line 52, in
>   addItem
>       item = Priority(subject = g.textBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c'), priority = g.textBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c')) AttributeError: 'GuiPart' object has no attribute 'textBox'
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Here is what I have done:

```
# priorities.py
#   GUI program to manage priorities

from tkinter import *

class Priority:

    def __init__(self, subject, priority):
        self.subject = subject
        self.priority = priority

    def subject(self):
        return self.subject

    def priority(self):
        return self.priority


class GuiPart:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = self.createWindow()

    def createWindow(self):

        root = Tk()
        root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        root.title("Priorities")

        return root

    def createWidgets(self):

        Button(self.root,
               text = "Add",
               command = self.addItem).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W + E)

        Button(self.root,
               text="Remove",
               command = self.removeItem).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W + E)

        Button(self.root,
               text="Edit",
               command = self.editItem).grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = W + E)

        listBox = Listbox(width = 30).grid(row = 1, sticky = W + E, columnspan = 3)

        textBox = Text(height=10, width=30).grid(row = 3, columnspan = 3, sticky = W + E + N + S)


    def addItem(self):
        item = Priority(subject = g.textBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c'), priority = g.textBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c'))

        g.listBox.insert(END, item)

    def removeItem(self):
       pass

    def editItem(self):
        pass

class Client:
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = GuiPart()
    g.createWidgets()
    g.root.mainloop()
```

I'm using Python 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understood your aim, you are trying to describe a priority by allowing the user to type, within the text zone widget, its information which consists in its subject and  order; after that, the user can click on the "Add" button to insert the priority information into your list box.

There are lot of things to consider around your code. If I go to fix and comment them one by one, I believe my answer will be long while I feel lazy today.

I think my program below is easy to understand (ask a clarification otherwise). I did not find specifications inherent to how the propriety information is typed in the text zone. So my program below works under the assumption the user types the priority subject on the first line of the text area, and then uses a new line to type the priority order.  The click on "Add" button will lead to the insertion of these 2 data on the same line of the text box widget as shown below:

[image]

Here is an MCVE:

```
import tkinter as tk

class ProioritiesManager(tk.Frame):

   def __init__(self, master):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
       self.master = master
       self.master.resizable(width = False, height = False)
       self.master.title("Priorities")
       self.create_buttons()
       self.create_listbox()
       self.create_priorities_description_zone()

   def create_buttons(self):
       add_item = tk.Button(self.master, text='Add', command=self.add_item)
       add_item.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
       remove_item = tk.Button(self.master, text='Remove', command=self.remove_item)
       remove_item.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
       edit_item = tk.Button(self.master, text='Edit', command=self.edit_item)
       edit_item.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

   def create_listbox(self):
       self.item_alternatives = tk.Listbox(self.master, width=30)
       self.item_alternatives.grid(row=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E, columnspan=3)   

   def create_priorities_description_zone(self):       
       self.priority_text_zone = tk.Text(self.master, height=10, width=30)
       self.priority_text_zone.grid(row=3, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S)

   def get_priority_subject(self):
       return self.priority_text_zone.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

   def get_priority_order(self):
       return self.priority_text_zone.get('2.0', '2.0 lineend')  

   def add_item(self):
       self.item_alternatives.insert(tk.END, self.get_priority_subject()+'  '+ self.get_priority_order())

   def remove_item(self):
       pass

   def edit_item(self):
       pass



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    ProioritiesManager(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

If you want to give a good UX to your GUI then it would be nice if you add a button to allow the user to clear the content of the text area so that he can type in a new priority:

[image]

For this purpose, you can add a rest button to `create_buttons()` function by adding these 2 lines of code:

```
clear_text_area = tk.Button(self.master, text='Reset', command=self.reset_priority_text_zone)
clear_text_area.grid(row=4, column=2)
```

The callback `reset_priority_text_zone()` is defined this way:

```
def reset_priority_text_zone(self):
       self.priority_text_zone.delete('1.0', tk.END)
```

Comment: you are welcome, if there is something you do not understand in my code, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

These Lines are causing Error :

```
listBox = Listbox(width = 30).grid(row = 1, sticky = W + E, columnspan = 3)
textBox = Text(height=10, width=30).grid(row = 3, columnspan = 3, sticky = W + E + N + S)
```

Do it like this:

```
self.listBox = Listbox(self.root,width = 30)
self.listBox.grid(row = 1, sticky = W + E, columnspan = 3)
self.textBox = Text(self.root,height=10, width=30)
self.textBox.grid(row = 3, columnspan = 3, sticky = W + E + N + S)
```

Actually you are not creating listBox and textBox objects instead grid is returning to listBox and textBox